# login using custom/added field to the user profile in liferay 7.4

Tags: authentication, liferay, user-profile

I am trying to add new field to the user profile (student number) and allow users to login using either  email or the new field (student number) with the same password for both.

I have overridden login.jsp to allow both Email and Student Number.
My idea is to override the login action command with something similar to the code below:

```
@Component(
    property = {
        "javax.portlet.name=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet",
        "mvc.command.name=/login/login"
    },
    service = MVCActionCommand.class
)
public class CustomLoginActionCommand extends BaseMVCActionCommand {

    @Override
    protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(
            WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        
        HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(
            PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
        
        HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(
            actionResponse);

        String login = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "login");
        String password = actionRequest.getParameter("password");
        boolean rememberMe = ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "rememberMe");
        
        String authType = CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_EA;
        String email = "";
        
       if(isValidEmail(login)){ //if the user trying to login with his email
            email = login ;
        }
        else if(isNumeric(login)){ //check if the user trying to login with his student number
            //fetch User by Student Number (login)
            //e.g. fetchUserByStudentNumber(login)
            //get the Email Adress for the retrieved user object and use it to login
            email = user.getEmailAddress();
        }
        else{
            // Exception
        }
        
        AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.login(request, response, email, password, rememberMe, authType);
        
        actionResponse.sendRedirect(themeDisplay.getPathMain());
    }
}
```

- is this the right way to achive similar requierment?
- in Liferay 7.4 U46+, we can extend supported system services with Liferay Objects. so I have two options to extend the User Profile, 1- by adding a new field to the User object. or 2- by creating a new "custom field". which option is better?
- in both options, how to force unique values in the added field (student number)?
- how to retrieve user object by using added field (*fetchUserByStudentNumber*)?

Appreciate your feedback!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the portal login command is possible, but I would rather use a custom `Authenticator` to not overwrite other logic implemented in the MVC action component. As you want booth (mail and student number), you could implement `authenticateByEmailAddress` like in [Password-Based-Authentication-Pipelines](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018161751-Password-Based-Authentication-Pipelines-) and check both authentication results with a boolean `OR` approach.

Extending portal model objects should rather be implemented via `Custom Fields`. Fetching a user like in `fetchUserByStudentNumber` you will probably need the `ExpandoValue` service and a dynamic query. Maybe there are better approached, but this is what comes into my mind first.